# Nest js and typeorm custom repository issue

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a small question about custom repositories in nestjs.

I have the following logic when a request comes in (for example for user entity).

A controller for the user requests -> pass the data to a service -> service does the logic and parsing -> call the custom repository for basic data commands (save, update, get etc.).

So i have the following repository:

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  /**
   * Get a user by id
   * @param id
   */
  async getUserById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return await this.findOne({
      where: [{ id }],
    });
  }

}
```

And the service looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
        private userRepository: UserRepository
    ){
    }

    /**
     * Returns a user object by id
     * @param id
     */
    async getUserById(id: number): Promise<User>{
        return await this.userRepository.getUserById(id);
    }
}
```

If it matters the user module is:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, UserRepository])
    ],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService],
    exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule{
}
```

But for some reason when i call getUserById i get the following error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined"

Iam able to fix it if i change the repository function to this:

```
return await getRepository(User).findOne({where: [{ id }]})
```

But it seems like a messy solution, any ideas why it doesnt work in the original way?

Thank in advance,
Gabi.

Comment: Issue resolved?

Comment: Nope.. Still the same issue

Comment: Please read the link here. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7370#issuecomment-778698027 I fix my issue with the OP suggestion

Answer (score 4):

you don't need @InjectRepository if you use Custom repository.
You need @InjectRepository when you inject your repository in service like

```
constructor(
  @InjectRepository(User)
  private readonly userService: Repository<User>
){}
```

Answer (score 2):

Custom repositories don't need to be injected with

```
@InjectRepository(UserRepository)
```

You should remove that line. It could be the reason for your error.